# mysql on wamp is not working after installing uniform server(uninstalled now)

Tags: mysql, wampserver

MYSQL was working fine on wamp for me before I installed uniform server.
I uninstalled uniform server but Mysql is not working on wamp now.
I tried looking at the registry files but could not find anything for uniform server.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing WAMP. Don't forget to backup your DBs before.

Comment: How do I backup, its not letting me to connect to PHPMyadmin

Comment: #2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Comment: You can use other ways to backup. Look here: [Backup MySQL Databases](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/using-php-to-backup-mysql-databases.aspx)